# Simulating a Ball Rolling Down a Slope - HTML5 Canvas JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, physics

How can I simulate a ball rolling down a given slope using HTML5 canvas and JavaScript? Can someone provide code as to how to do this?

Comment: This is not a programming question.  Why don't you try and then ask if you have problems.  Read up on the html5 canvas methods.

Comment: I don't know how to even start programming this, since I don't know the physics behind it. And the html5 canvas methods are just the basic draw rectangle, draw path kind of thing.

Comment: I have no clue how to start writing a physics simulation using JS and cavas either but I have this other tool called google: http://www.google.com/search?q=canvas+physics+library the first result looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but the defacto standard for javascript-based physics is called Box2DJS.

You can find it here: http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/